# Telegraf.js custom keyboard как сделать кнопку назад?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

[image: Не знаю как делать возврат к предыдущему меню.]

Не знаю как делать возврат к предыдущему меню.

```
bot.command('course', ctx => { // Возврат вот сюда после нажатия кнопки Back внизу
    ctx.replyWithHTML('<b>Courses</b>', Markup.keyboard(
        [
            ['Editors', 'Reviews'],
            ['JS']
        ]
    ).resize())
})

bot.hears('JS', ctx => {
    ctx.replyWithHTML('<b>Courses</b>', Markup.keyboard(
        [
            ['Angular', 'React'],
            ['Node'], ['Back'] //  При нажатии на Back возращалось на предыдущее меню
        ]
    ).resize())
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В слушатель, который отправляет нужную клавиатуру, добавьте регулярное выражение с командами. В данном случае `Back` будет возвращать в меню курсов.

Если требуется логическое `назад`, то смотрите в сторону [сцен](https://telegraf.js.org/modules/Scenes.html).

```js
bot.command(/^(course|Back)$/i, ctx => { // Возврат вот сюда после нажатия кнопки Back внизу
    ctx.replyWithHTML('<b>Courses</b>', Markup.keyboard(
        [
            ['Editors', 'Reviews'],
            ['JS']
        ]
    ).resize())
})
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но функция .command параметром принимает только текст или массив. Пожтому я переделал слушатель с .command на bot.hears(/\/course|Back/, ctx => {... и все работает.